# ckeditor how can we open Image Properties window?

Tags: php, ckeditor

I am using CkEditor for by replacing a text area. 
I want to open the image property window on custom event outside the editor. anchor tag onclick in JavaScript function. i have used the following code for listing of events available to me for an editor instance

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( element, { customConfig : 'ckeditor/config.js' }  );      

for(var i in CKEDITOR.instances)
{  
    console.log(CKEDITOR.instances[i]._.events); 
}
```

Also tried this code to open dialog :

```
dialogObj = new CKEDITOR.dialog( CKEDITOR.instances[i], 'smiley' );
dialogObj.show();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your instance is called editor1 you can call the smiley dialog it this way:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.execCommand('smiley')
```